# Spring boot MongoDB regex criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm struggling with regex match in MongoDB / Spring Boot.

This match works fine in MondoDB directly:

```
{ 
  $match : {
    name: {
      $regex: /\bskil/, 
      $options: 'i'
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried translating this into Criteria on Spring Boot like this:

```
Criteria.where("name").regex("\bskil", "i")
```

But it does not work.

Spring boot logs the following:

```
{ 
  "$match" : { 
    "name" : { 
      "$regularExpression" : { 
        "pattern" : "\bskil", 
        "options" : "i"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.12.RELEASE and upgrading is not an option right now.

Comment: what is your spring data mongodb version?

Comment: Can you try this Criteria.where("name").regex("\\bskil", "i")